# How to use multiple, independent Handlebars instances in the same environment?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

For various testing reasons, I want to be able to have multiple 'instances' of Handlebars in the same process.

But the main export from `require('handlebars')` to be a global singleton.

What if I want to run async tests against multiple, independent copies of Handlebars in a single Node process? Is there some way to get a fresh, unmodified copy of Handlebars for each test, i.e. with no custom helpers/partials registered, without having to start a whole new process each time?

Answer (score 8):

Found it: `Handlebars.create()`

https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime.html#handlebars-create

> Creates an isolated Handlebars environment
>
> Each environment has its own helpers and partials. This is only necessary for use cases that demand distinct helpers or partials. Most use cases can use the root Handlebars environment directly.
>
> Templates created for a given environment are bound to that environment. This means that templates that need to run in multiple environments will need to be recompiled or reconstructed via Handlebars.template for each environment. This applies to partials as well.

Comment: Upvoted but the link provided is out of date -- it's now moved here: https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime.html#handlebars-create